What's the expected value of a coin game in which I win $N$ or lose $3N/4$?
This should have a simple solution but I'm having a hard time trying to understand it. If I play a game in which I win $20$ dollars when a coin lands heads and lose $15$ when it lands tails, the expected value is $2.5$, so it'd be rational to play the game.
Now suppose I have $n$ dollars and if heads, I double my money and if tails, I keep $n/4$. If $n$ happens to be $20$ then this is identical to the original game. In every turn, the game will have a positive expected value of $0.125n$, so the rational thing would be to play it.
But if we imagine for simplicity that the coins alternate between heads and tails, then first I'll start with $n$ and after the first heads I'll have $2n$, and then after tails I'll have $0.5n$. After another two tosses I'll have $0.25n$ and so on, and it makes no difference if the coin first lands tails. So I'll quickly run out of money. I also ran some simulations and the numbers always end up close to zero. So what'd be the rational thing to do?
I think that, either I shouldn't use the expected value here and instead use something like the weighted geometric mean, or it's just that on most possible cases I lose money, but there are a few in which I win a lot of money so the expected value is still positive and I should play the game, at least in theory.
But also I'm thinking that, if this is a bad game to play, then it'd be a good game for a casino to offer since afaik it is a zero sum game (when I win the casino loses and the other way around). But if I go every week with $100$ dollars taken from my salary to play this game only once, I would end up making money on the long run, which means the casino would lose money, and it doesn't matter whether it's $100$ I take every week or any other amount.

As to the apparent "paradox", it's as you say.  In running some quick simulations, starting with $100$, I got up to $25600$.  Of course, the most you can possibly lose is $100$.

It's right to say that expectation is, at best, an incomplete kind to the quality of a game.  For a cheaper example, just imagine a game that pays a fortune on a trillion to one shot but wipes you out otherwise.  No matter the size of the fortune, you'll never make money on this game despite the positive expectation.

In finance, one often looks at ratios...expected gain divided by standard deviation or such.  If you only look at expectation then leveraging looks purely good, which it isn't.  In the ratio, leverage looks irrelevant.

@lulu maybe we're using different logic? Here is my (javascript) code: let x = 100; for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++)  x *= (tossCoin() ? 2 : 1/4); and const tossCoin = () => Math.random() > 0.5;

Oh, I'm sure we are running the same game.  Most of the time you get wiped out.  But in 100 simulations or so, I got up to a fortune a couple times.  It's very unstable, of course.  One hit of $25600$ makes up for a whole lot of ruins.

You would probably like to read about the Kelly criterion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion

So I just asked AI and said the formula for the expected value after $T$ times is just $N \times E^T$ which in this case is $N \left(\frac{9}{8}\right)^T$. Is that formula correct? I was expecting it to be a lot more intricate given the number of possible combinations but at least for the case of 1 and 2 coin tosses it seems to work if you add up all possible combinations.

Yes, it is that simple.  Because multiplication is commutative the final amount only depends on the number of wins, not on the order of wins and losses.  For a more extreme example see here
